# IPythonからシステムシェルのコマンド使用の際の引数について

Tags: python, command-line

例えば

```
!less "book.csv"
```

は実行可能ですが、

```
file = "book.csv"
!less file
```

だとエラーになってしまいます。
これは機能的に無理なのでしょうか。
その場合、ループして複数のファイルに対してコマンドを実行したいのですがそれも不可能ということになってしまうのでしょうか

Answer (score 2):

`$variable` あるいは `{variable}` の形式で変数を渡すことが可能です

参考: IPython [Shell Assignment](https://ipython.readthedocs.io/en/stable/interactive/python-ipython-diff.html#shell-assignment)

```py
file = "book.csv"
out = !cat $file
print(out.l)
```